# Is there a way to customize login error message?

Tags: administration, login, admin, login-errors

Is there a way to customize login error message?

Currently, the login message always shows "Please check your username and password. If you still can't log in, contact your Salesforce administrator."

The user logging in cannot determine if they have reached the number of invalid login attempts. I am trying to find a way to customize this message and also find a way to add a behavior that changes this message when the maximum invalid login attempts have been reached.

I am also trying to look for a way to change the login failure in Salesforce communities which always outputs "Please check your username and password. If you still can't log in, contact your axa-partner-community administrator"

[image]

[image: salesforce error message]

[image: Maximum invalid attempts]

Comment: _The user logging in cannot determine if they have reached the number of invalid login attempts_ : that is intentional for security reasons. Therefore you can't customize the message. You can write your own login page with your own messages.